# Bash, Expect : Execution of command after SSH is not working

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I need to login to a VM and execute some command there. I have gone through all question related to the same topic but did not find any solution with EXPECT. I am using EXPECT as I need to pass the password while using SSH.

I am getting "command not found error" while executing my script but manually, it is working fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set user [lindex $argv 0]
set to [lindex $argv 1]
set pass [lindex $argv 2]
set command [lindex $argv 3]
puts "$user, $to , $command and $pass ."
# connect via scp
spawn sudo ssh -t -t -v $user@$to << EOF
    ls
EOF

#######################
expect {
-re ".*es.*o.*" {
exp_send "yes\r"
exp_continue
}
-re ".*sword.*" {
exp_send $pass\n
}
}
interact
```

Error received :

> spawn sudo ssh -t -t -v username@server_ip << EOF
>   Invalid command name "ls"
>       while executing "ls"
>       (file "./establishSSHConnection.sh" line 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to send commands to the remote system in a 'here' doc:

```
spawn sudo ssh -t -t -v $user@$to << EOF
    ls
EOF
```

Instead, you should use 'exp_send' to send the ls command just before 'interact' i.e., remove the 'here' doc:

```
spawn sudo ssh -t -t -v $user@$to
```

And put the ls command here at the end:

```
expect {
    -re ".*es.*o.*" {
        exp_send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    -re ".*sword.*" {
        exp_send "$pass\r"
    }
}
exp_send "ls\r"
interact
```

EDIT:

Ah, I misunderstood.  If you just want to run the command then you'll need to tell the other end to close the connection:

```
expect {
    -re ".*es.*o.*" {
        exp_send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    -re ".*sword.*" {
        exp_send "$pass\r"
    }
}
exp_send "ls\r"
exp_send "exit\r"
expect {
    eof {puts "Connection closed"}
    timeout {puts "Connection timed out"}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jeff for your help. I changed the code as per your suggestion but it is still not executing the command, it just SSH to the server and leave terminal open towards the server.

Answer (score 1):

Expect (being built atop Tcl) does not have here documents.

If you want to execute the command remotely and then end the ssh session, do

```
set command "ls -lrt"  ; # for example
spawn sudo ssh -t -t -v $user@$to $command
# ... log in logic
expect eof
```